# How to resolve Gitlab Hook Plugin installation issue with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have jenkins 2.190.1 and while installing GitLab plugin version 1.4.2, I am getting this error.

> "ruby-runtime version 0.12 is missing. To fix, install version 0.12 or later"
>
> jenkins.util.io.CompositeIOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\ruby-runtime'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.